# What should I put in home directory in my app, if there is no SDCard in phone?

Tags: android

I know stackoverflow is not a research site, but my problem is related to app development only.

I am building an image gallery app. I am giving user an option which directory to scan for images.

But by default I need to set a path. Generally, I'm only following my phone to build it which has an SDCard. So I was using `/mnt/sdcard`. But what should I use for the phone which does not have an SDCard. I do not want to put `root(/)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just check if sd card is present or not, if it is present set path as *mnt/sdcard*

or set path as null and show user a popup message that SD card is not present and close your application..

you can use below method to know if sdcard is present or not

```
public static boolean isSdPresent() {

return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition, in think, `/` would not work on phones that aren't rooted

Comment: umm....mine was not rooted still it was working but ya... i have to setup isReadable() which returns false in 90% files. Yes '/'sums up to be useless